Overleaf, eps to pdf error, cannot find file?
Working on my presentation for my thesis and am having some problems with Overleaf. Using beamer if it makes any difference
Packages Used
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}
\epstopdfsetup{ suffix=,}

Code
\begin{frame}{State Estimation Overview}
\begin{figure}[H]
 \begin{center}
\includegraphics[]{template/figures/StateEstimationSteps}
 \end{center}\vspace{-2mm}
  \caption{CAPTION}
  \label{Stateestmation}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

Here is the log output
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <template/figures/StateEstimationSteps.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2024-07-29 18:24:41
(epstopdf)                    size: 882830 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <./StateEstimationSteps.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=./StateEstimationSteps.pdf template/figures/StateEstimationSteps.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 154.
runsystem(epstopdf --outfile=./StateEstimationSteps.pdf template/figures/StateEstimationSteps.eps)...executed.

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <./StateEstimationSteps.pdf>.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `./StateEstimationSteps.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

I have tried looking online but have not had any luck at all, please help!

Unrelated to your question, but you don't need [H] as beamer does not have a floating mechanism. You also don't need the center environment, as figures are automatically centred in beamer. If you remove this, you probably also don't need to manually mess with the vertical spacing.

You can probably remove the whole block \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{epstopdf} \epstopdfsetup{outdir=./} \epstopdfsetup{ suffix=,}. Beamer automatically loads graphicx and conversion from eps to pdf is automatic nowadays.

Yeah honestly I was just entering whatever I could to get it to work. And thank you!

Lol nvm, for some reason I needed to change the call to the figure as such:
{figures/StateEstimationSteps}

ie) delete the first part of the path.
